# Using sum in select statement without GROUP by

Tags: sql, oracle, select, toad

```
select
   Col1,
   Col1/sum(Col1) as Fraction
from MyTable
```

This one will not return the desired result. If I add `Gruop by Col1` then it will return a bunch of 1'a in the second column. **How can I get around the problem?**

Basically I want to treat the `sum(Col1)` as constant parameter. I can use `with` statement but I want a solution where I don't add another `select` statement.

I am using Toad and selecting from an Oracle database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUM` in its analytic form:

```
select
  col1,
  col1 / sum(col1) over () fraction
from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem but I have no idea why :D Can you add a couple of words on whats going?

Comment: As written, this function returns sum of all COL1 values, in the whole table (as there's no PARTITION BY clause). As analytic functions don't group rows, query doesn't require GROUP BY clause. Therefore, you got what you wanted - summary without additional SELECT statement.